# What are the irreducible components of the algebraic set $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)$ in $\mathbb{A}^3_K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What are the irreducible components of the algebraic set $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)$ in $\mathbb{A}^3_K$? Here I"m just letting $K$ be an algebraically closed set.

I've tried to solve this problem and I've found that $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)=V(x,z) \cup V(y^2-z)$.Is this solution correct?

Normally, what I do is take the equations determining an algebraic set $V(I)$, and usually one of them factors so that $V(I)$ decomposes as $V(J_1)\cup V(J_2)\cup\cdots$ or something. After breaking things down enough, I can eventually find that $K[x,y,z]/J_i$ is an integral domain, so $J_i$ is prime, and $V(J_i)$ is irreducible.Are there any other ways of solving this problem?

Comment: There are other ways, but I think the approach you have learned is the easiest, atleast for examples like this. For example, $k[x, y, z]/(y^2-z)=k[x, y]$, so is clearly an integral domain, and thus irreducible. Likewise, $k[x, y, z]/(x, z)=k[y]$, so that we have reached a decomposition, atleast of the righthand side. I would check your equality again, since $(10, 1, 1)$ lies in the right but not the left.

Comment: For the record: your solution is **not correct** because $V(y^2-z)$ is **not** included  in $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)$. Check it with the point $(17,1,1)$...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Finally I managed to show that $Vx^2-yz,xy-z)=V(x,z) \cup V(y^3-z)$.Is this correct?

Comment: Dear Arpit, unfortunately no: again that darned point $(17,1, 1) $ is in the right-hand side of your "equality", but not on the left-hand side...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for being so polite! I'm Sorry.I've found that $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)=V(x,z) \cup V(x-y^2,y^3-z)$.(Actually this I what I wrote in the comment below!)Is this correct?

Comment: Dear Arpit, bravo:  that last equality is totally correct and indeed yields the decomposition of the left-hand variety into its irreducible components. Geometrically, the intersection of the two given  quadrics in $\mathbb A^3$ has  thus been shown to be the union of a line and of a twisted cubic curve, as correctly stated by SpamIAm.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks ! One more doubt:I can see that $V(x,z)$ and $V(x-y^2,y^3-z)$ are irreducibles,but I can't see that $V(x,z) \cup V(x-y^2,y^3-z)$  is decomposition into irreducible "components" ?(Sorry for troubling you for my silly doubts).

Comment: This is topology: if a space is a union of finitely many  irreducible closed subspaces without any inclusions between them, then these irreducible subspaces  are the irreducible components of the space. Check it or ask it as another question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry for replying late.Let me first try this problem.Thanks for your time.Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Since $xy - z \in \langle x^2 - yz, xy - z \rangle$, we have $z = xy$, hence we can replace $z$ with $xy$ in the first generator.  Then
$$
\langle x^2 - yz, xy - z \rangle = \langle x^2 - xy^2, xy - z \rangle = \langle x(x - y^2), xy - z \rangle \, .
$$
Do you see how to proceed?  In the end, I get the union of a line and the twisted cubic.

In response to your question below, modding out by $x - y^2$ is basically the same as setting $x = y^2$.  So
$$
\frac{k[x,y,z]}{\langle y^3 - z, x - y^2 \rangle} \cong k[y^2, y, y^3] = k[y] \, .
$$

Comment: Sorry for replying late.Following your hint I've found that $V(x^2-yz,xy-z)=V(x,z) \cup V(x-y^2,y^3-z)$ .Clearly $<(x,z)>$ is prime ideal but I'm unable in proving that $<(x-y^2,y^3-z)>$ is prime in $ \mathbb C[x,y,z]$.Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited to respond to your question.